# Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ProtocolCommandListener

Tags: linux, apache, struts2

I got Below error when I try to deploy my application on Apache Tomcat.
The server is based on linux.
I have already found that `ProtocolCommandListener` class is in `comment-net.jar` which is already in lib.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ProtocolCommandListener
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2532)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2842)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1718)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:403)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:354)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:468)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:264)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:298)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4076)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.net.ProtocolCommandListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        ... 31 more
```

Comment: How do you use it? Which version of commons-net?

Comment: You are probably including garbage in your ear/war. Please ensure you are including all and only the right versions of the libraries needed. Once.